# How to use OpenSL ES to play audio on a call in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, ivr, opensl

I found from one thread that OpenSL ES can be used in Android to play audio in phone call without enabling speaker phone mode. But i don't know how to do that. is there any working example?

Comment: _"I found from one thread that OpenSL ES can be used in Android to play audio in phone call without enabling speaker phone mode."_ That doesn't sound correct to me. There are certainly platform-specific ways to achieve this on certain devices, but they're not really related to OpenSL ES, and would require root access and/or a modified Android ROM.